# Some non-trivial and explicit shape of  Kähler cone?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

It may be difficult to give some special and non-trivial examples of Kähler cones.The examples I know are the following:

1. for complex tori, the Kähler cone is just the set of  positive hermitian matrices;
2. for a Kähler manifold $M$ with $h^{1,1}(M)=1$, then the Kähler cone is just $\mathbb{R}_{+}$.

Thus in order to give a non-trivial example, firstly we must require $h^{1,1}(M)>1$. I would like to see an example such that:

1. the cone equation or the boundary of the cone is clear;
2. $c_{1}(M)>0$, or the sign of $c_{1}(M)$ is not definite (are there some intresting manifolds of this type?).

Of course, any explicit shape will be welcome.

Comment: Given that the question currently has $5$ downvotes and one close vote (mine) stemming from its inauspicious beginning, it might be best to close and delete it and start again from scratch.  I wonder what the moderators think of this?

Comment: This is a genuine question, I don't quite see why it is down-voted. If you want to look for non-trivial examples where the cone can be explicitly described, one case to consider is toric varieties, you might have a look at Section 6 in the book http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~dac/toric.html . Ample cone can be explicitly described as well for Fano surfaces. If you want the case when $C_1$ is not necessarily ample, you should definitely look in the article http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3825   

Comment: I guess that the OP is a non-native english speaker, and this would explain the high number of grammar mistakes. However, I also think that this is a genuine question which does not deserve so many downvotes, so I took the liberty of fixing the english and the LateX (needless to say, always respecting the author).

Comment: The question was downvoted because in its original form it was, literally, random noise (check the edit history).  I agree that it's a perfectly good question now.  I would like to withdraw my vote to close.  